# Backup application files using Android auto backup

Tags: android, realm, android-backup-service

I'm trying to use Android auto backup feature in Android 6 and lower, but after re-installing my app, nothing will be restored.

**Manifest:**

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:backupAgent=".BackupAgent"
            android:fullBackupOnly="true"
            android:fullBackupContent="true"
            android:name="com.App">

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
                android:value="API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

**BackupAgent:**

```
public class BackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        BackupHelper helper = new FileBackupHelper(getApplicationContext(), Realm.getDefaultInstance().getPath());

        addHelper("database", helper);
    }
}
```

**Fragment which uses Realm:**

```
public class NewBlockNumber extends Fragment implements Validator.ValidationListener {
    private Realm mRealm;
    private RealmChangeListener mRealmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange() {
            BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(getContext());
            bm.dataChanged();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        mRealm.addChangeListener(mRealmChangeListener);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to this document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html , you need to override the `onBackup` and `onRestore`.

Comment: @beeender I extended `BackupAgentHelper`, so implementing those methods is not necessary.

Comment: `new FileBackupHelper(getApplicationContext(), Realm.getDefaultInstance().getPath());` I doubt you might need to pass the file name instead of the whole path here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the FileBackupHelper with the filename of the db, not the path. The absolute Path is then resolved by the BackupAgent. You can debug it and trace all the steps to check that out.
I have this code running in my app and it works perfectly.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    FileBackupHelper hosts = new FileBackupHelper(this, Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration().getRealmFileName());
    addHelper(Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration().getRealmFileName(), hosts);
}

@Override
public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data,
                     ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    Log.w("Backup", "onBackup");
    // Hold the lock while the FileBackupHelper performs backup
    synchronized (MainActivity.sDataLock) {
        Log.w("Backup", "backing up...");
        super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode,
                      ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    Log.w("Backup", "onRestore");
    // Hold the lock while the FileBackupHelper restores the file
    synchronized (MainActivity.sDataLock) {
        Log.w("Backup", "Restoring data...");
        super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
    }
}
```